# Saving reorder of TableView cells using NSCoding

Tags: swift2, tableview, uitableview, nscoding

I have an `iOS` project I'm working on using `Xcode7` and `Swift2`.  I have a `TableView` that fetches an `array` from `NSCoding`.  I have it started so the user can reorder the `TableViewCells` in the `TableView`.  However I need it to save the new order once the user is finished and clicks 'done' which is a `UIBarButtonItem`.  I have a value in my `NSCoding` `object` called `cellOrder`. I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32321093/save-order-of-uitableviewcells/32337664#32337664) and saw this for `CoreData`.  How how would I do this for `NSCoding` and where do I save it?

I have the following code started for the `TableViewCell` movement:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let itemToMove = details[fromIndexPath.row]

    details.removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.row)

    details.insert(itemToMove, atIndex: toIndexPath.row)

}
```

`details` is the array my data is kept in, using `NSCoding`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided the best way for me was to save the `details` `array` to `NSUserDefaults` after the the reorder was done.  I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240848/how-to-save-an-array-of-objects-to-nsuserdefault-with-swift) how to convert the `NSObject` to `NSData` to be saved.  My code for the `moveRowAtIndexPath` section is now:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let itemToMove = details[fromIndexPath.row]

    details.removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.row)

    details.insert(itemToMove, atIndex: toIndexPath.row)

    // Archive NSObject and save as NSData
    let myData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(details)

    // NSUserDefaults Save for Reorder of cells
    reportDefaults.setObject(myData, forKey: "savedReportListKEY")
    reportDefaults.synchronize()

    // NSCoding Save
    saveReport()

}
```